# ASP.NET 5 DNU publish overwrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I use Jenkins to publish my site but have some problem

```
Error: The process cannot access the file 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

It looks like my website is using the .dll so I can't overwrite it. I try to publish by Visual Studio it work. What VS do is publish to temp folder then deploy to final path there is deploy command by VS

```
Publishing with publish method [FileSystem]
Publishing files to C:\inetpub\HubbleRebuild
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='\PublishTemp\Website52\' -dest:contentPath='C:\inetpub\Website' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule]
```

At first, I want to overwrite at publish but I find this [dnu publish should handle --out pointing to an existing directory](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2303) . It look like not support now. So I think I need to publish by following the VS way and an other problem is how can I overwrite when deploy and how to define which file I don't want to overwrite.

Comment: Stop your application before trying to publish. This is getting fixed in RC2 if you publish to IIS.

Comment: Do you have more information about this fix?

Comment: I don't know the details about the fiy, but it wouldn't matter for you until RC2 is released. RC2 now exclusively supports dotnet-cli and dnx (which includes dnu) is deprecated and it hasn't received any feature  updates or fixes since the ASP.NET Core team started migrating to dotnet-cli. The catch is, there isn't a full VS 2015 IDE support for dotnet cli yet. command line stuff works though. ASP.NET Core RC2 is supposed to be released mid-May 2016 with preview 1 of the tooling and preview 2 scheduled for end of June

Comment: Check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/ for more about the ASP.NET Core roadmap

Comment: Sorry, I use RC1 I forgot to mention that

Comment: @MichaelMao - you can find details here: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/81

Comment: @Pawel thank you. It looks like I need to update to RC2

Comment: @MichaelMao - yes, RC2 should be released this week.

Comment: @Pawel Where the information from could you share with me?

Comment: @MichaelMao - it was release today. Here is the announcement: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use 2 commands on my Jenkins to publish my site and it works good.

1.dnu pulibsh to temp folder

2.deploy this temp folder to target site

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='\PublishTemp\Website52\' -dest:contentPath='C:\inetpub\Website' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule
```

But my Jenkins server don't have **Microsoft Web Deploy V3** only **Microsoft Web Deploy** when I use the command it was failed because `disablerule:BackupRule` after I remove this section it's work.

The log file not overwrite and the new feature update.